# Searching for the correct AVD settings to emulate an Samsung Galaxy Nexus (using android-4.x, ICS)

Tags: android, configuration, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-virtual-device

I recently upgraded my android sandbox to handle Icecream Sandwich (ICS, aka android-4). Unluckily I was unable to find configuration data for the newest android-based flagship; Samsung's Galaxy Nexus.

Can anyone help witht the specific configuration parameters?

Regs,
Rob

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here are the AVD settings :

- Resolution : 720 x 1280
- Abstracted LCD density : 316
- Max VM application heap size : 48
- Device ram size : 1024

If you can't manually enter the LCD density (316), use the nearest value (320).

Comment: Many thanks for your quick answer. Can you provide some source to this data?

Comment: Found it on Wikipedia : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_displays_by_pixel_density#Samsung (and another website in french for the memory settings)

Comment: How do you set the density? The AVD edit dialog only allows for pre-defined items in a select list, not free text: http://cl.ly/image/2R3g3M2y0f36

Comment: That's strange, be sure you have the latest SDK tools installed.

Comment: I have the latest SDK and I can select 320 or 213. Cant type it

Comment: Same here. Typing is not allowed in the Density field.

Answer (score 8):

I used the built in skin WXGA720, it has same spec's